# send array session from .cs file to script in aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using session to send value of array from .cs file to variable in script of aspx file
but it don't return exactly. how can i do that?

in my aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="flash">
    function abc() {
                        alert(NhacSi[0]);
                    }
    var NhacSi = '<%=NhacSi%>';
</script>
```

in my cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] art = { "Various Artists", "art2", "atr3" };
    Session["NhacSi"] = art;
}
public string[] NhacSi { get { return (string[])Session["NhacSi"]; } }
```

Thank everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like RegisterClientStartupScript or RegisterClientScriptBlock to write Javascript from your cs file. This way you can use it as a variable in Javascript.

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Key", string.Format("var       NhacSi = {0};", this.Session["NhacSi"].ToString(), true);
```